# Limits as $x \rightarrow \infty$ and $y \rightarrow 0$ (simultaneously) of product expressions involving $x$ and $y$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have, for the first time, stumbled onto a problem where two variables are approaching infinity and zero simultaneously, and I have to determine the limit of a product involving the two. Mainly I am trying to understand whether or not an expression such as $x^ny^m$, $m>n$ converges to $0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ and $y \rightarrow 0$ simultaneously. I suspect that the higher order of exponentiation on $y$ would suggest that $y^m$ converges to $0$ faster than $x^n$ diverges to infinity whereby the product converges to $0$, but i have found no definitive answers online or anywhere else as to whether or not my intuition is correct on this.

So if anyone can provide a good explanation or point me in the direction of one, I would be very greatful.

As a side note, I stumbled on to this while reading a textbook chapter on nonparametric kernel density estimation. In one of the derivations it is implied that for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $h_1,h_2,...,h_q>0$ if we let $n\rightarrow \infty$, $\max_{1\leq s\leq q}h_s\rightarrow 0$ and $nh_1 h_2 ...h_q\rightarrow \infty$ then

$\sqrt{nh_1 h_2 ...h_q}\sum_{s=1}^q h_s\rightarrow 0$

I am thinking that the simpler phrasing of the question above would be sufficient for this result since

$
\sqrt{n \prod_{s=1}^q h_s}\sum_{s=1}^q h_s\leq 
\sqrt{n (\max_{1\leq s\leq q}h_s)^q} n \max_{1\leq s\leq q}h_s=
n(\max_{1\leq s\leq q}h_s)^{\frac{q}{2}+3}
\rightarrow 0$

given that the simpler version above is true.

Comment: "$x\to 0$ and $y\to \infty$ simultaneously" has not a precise mathematical meaning. You'll need to specify what do you mean by that.

Comment: Elaborating on the above comment: consider $\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)y(t)$ when $y(t)=1/t^2$ and $x(t)$ is one of $t, t^2, t^3$.